# Convert Date type

Tags: python, date, datetime, datecreated

Folks, Im using this code to extract twitter data, I want to export the created_at as Day, Month and Year,without the hour infos, but I getting this *Fri Jul 02 01:07:43 +0000 2021* and I want to get this *02/06/2021*

```
from TwitterSearch import *


try:
    
    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = consumer_key,
        consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
        access_token = access_token, 
        access_token_secret = access_token_secret)
    
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder() #Cria objeto do TwitterSearchOrder
    tso.set_keywords(['teste'], or_operator = True)
    tso.set_language('pt')
    
    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print('created_at:', tweet['created_at'], 'User_id: ', tweet['id_str'], 'Tweet: ',tweet['text'])
        
        created_at = tweet['created_at']
        user_id = tweet['id_str']
        texto = tweet['text']
        

        
        with open('tweet.json', 'a+') as output: 
            
            data = { 'created_at': created_at, 
                     'User_id': user_id, 
                     'tweet':texto
                   }
            output.write('{}\n'.format(json.dumps(data)))
            
except TwitterSearchException as e: 
    print(e)
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Module `datetime`. Use `strptime()` to parse the form you get from Twitter into a `datetime`, and `strftime()` to turn it back into the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, in particular the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

`datetime.datetime.strptime` can be used to convert a string to a datetime object, according to a given format string.

`datetime.datetime.strftime` will convert the `datetime` object back to a string, according to a given format string.

```
import datetime
mydate = 'Fri Jul 02 01:07:43 +0000 2021'
mydatetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
mydatetime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```